# Creating multiple objects within the same class in Python

Tags: python

I want to be able to return multiple objects of a class by using a method within the class. Something like this.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
    self.a = a

    def _multiple(self,*l):
        obj = []
        for i in l:
            o = self.__init__(self,i)
            obj.append(o)
        return obj
```

When I execute this on iPython (iPython 0.10 and Python 2.6.6) I get the following

```
In [466]: l = [1,2]
In [502]: A._multiple(*l)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

TypeError: unbound method _multiple() must be called with A instance as 
first argument (got int instance instead)
```

I'm definitely unclear about the invocation as well as the 'self' keyword usage. Could you help me out in getting this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive you need this kind of object relationship? I'd rather look for a different pattern...

Comment: Note that although you can use a classmethod for this, there isn't really a reason for it, you can have a separate function instead. Also, please don't start what is obviously a public API function name with an underscore. Call it `create` or `factory` not `_multiple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError: unbound method _multiple() must be called with A instance
>   as  first argument (got int instance instead)

The Error is self explanatory. It means that an instance method is being called as a Class method. To make the instance method as a class method add the decorator `@classmethod`

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    @classmethod
    def _multiple(cls,*l):
        #Create multiple instances of object `A`
        return [A(i) for i in l]

>>> l = [1,2]
>>> A._multiple(*l)
[<__main__.A instance at 0x066FBB20>, <__main__.A instance at 0x03D94580>]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a class method:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def _multiple(cls,*l):
        obj = []
        for i in l:
            o = cls(i)
            obj.append(o)
        return obj


>>> A._multiple(1, 2) # returns 2 A's
[<__main__.A instance at 0x02B7EFA8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x02B7EFD0>]
```

The `classmethod` decorator replaces the usual `self` as the first parameter with a reference to the class (in this case `A`). Note that doing it this way means if you subclass `A` and call `_multiple` on the subclass it will be passed the subclass instead.

```
class B(A): pass

>>> B._multiple(1, 2, 3)
[<__main__.B instance at 0x02B87C10>, <__main__.B instance at 0x02B87D28>, <__main__.B instance at 0x02B87CD8>]
```

would create a list of `B` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace:

```
 self.__init__(self, i)
```

With:

```
 A(i)
```

The reason for this is that the init method mutates the object on which it is called, and "self" is the current instance. You use the constructor (the same name as the class) to create a new instance.